# Using a multidimentional array with the LedControl.h library and Max7219 LED Matrix

Tags: arduino

I'm using the LedControl.h library with a Max7219 LED matrix and a MEGA2560 Arduino controller to display a word (one letter at a time) on the LED matrix.

```
void writeArduinoOnMatrix() {
  /* here is the data for the characters */
  char A[8] = {B00000000,B00111100,B01100110,B01100110,B01111110,B01100110,B01100110,B01100110};
  char B[8] = {B01111000,B01001000,B01001000,B01110000,B01001000,B01000100,B01000100,B01111100};
  char C[8] = {B00000000,B00011110,B00100000,B01000000,B01000000,B01000000,B00100000,B00011110};
  char D[8] = {B00000000,B00111000,B00100100,B00100010,B00100010,B00100100,B00111000,B00000000};
  char E[8] = {B00000000,B00111100,B00100000,B00111000,B00100000,B00100000,B00111100,B00000000};
  char F[8] = {B00000000,B00111100,B00100000,B00111000,B00100000,B00100000,B00100000,B00000000};
  char G[8] = {B00000000,B00111110,B00100000,B00100000,B00101110,B00100010,B00111110,B00000000};
  char H[8] = {B00000000,B00100100,B00100100,B00111100,B00100100,B00100100,B00100100,B00000000};
  char I[8] = {B00000000,B00111000,B00010000,B00010000,B00010000,B00010000,B00111000,B00000000};
  char J[8] = {B00000000,B00011100,B00001000,B00001000,B00001000,B00101000,B00111000,B00000000};
  char K[8] = {B00000000,B00100100,B00101000,B00110000,B00101000,B00100100,B00100100,B00000000};
  char L[8] = {B00000000,B00100000,B00100000,B00100000,B00100000,B00100000,B00111100,B00000000};
  char M[8] = {B00000000,B00000000,B01000100,B10101010,B10010010,B10000010,B10000010,B00000000};
  char N[8] = {B00000000,B00100010,B00110010,B00101010,B00100110,B00100010,B00000000,B00000000};
  char O[8] = {B00000000,B00111100,B01000010,B01000010,B01000010,B01000010,B00111100,B00000000};
  char P[8] = {B00000000,B00111000,B00100100,B00100100,B00111000,B00100000,B00100000,B00000000};
  char Q[8] = {B00000000,B00111100,B01000010,B01000010,B01000010,B01000110,B00111110,B00000001};
  char R[8] = {B00000000,B00111000,B00100100,B00100100,B00111000,B00100100,B00100100,B00000000};
  char S[8] = {B00000000,B00111100,B00100000,B00111100,B00000100,B00000100,B00111100,B00000000};
  char T[8] = {B00000000,B01111100,B00010000,B00010000,B00010000,B00010000,B00010000,B00000000};
  char U[8] = {B00000000,B01000010,B01000010,B01000010,B01000010,B00100100,B00011000,B00000000};
  char V[8] = {B00000000,B00100010,B00100010,B00100010,B00010100,B00010100,B00001000,B00000000};
  char W[8] = {B00000000,B10000010,B10010010,B01010100,B01010100,B00101000,B00000000,B00000000};
  char X[8] = {B00000000,B01000010,B00100100,B00011000,B00011000,B00100100,B01000010,B00000000};
  char Y[8] = {B00000000,B01000100,B00101000,B00010000,B00010000,B00010000,B00010000,B00000000};
  char Z[8] = {B00000000,B00111100,B00000100,B00001000,B00010000,B00100000,B00111100,B00000000};
  
  for(int col=0; col<8; col++) {
    lc.setRow(0,col,A[col]);
  }
  delay(500);
  for(int col=0; col<8; col++) {
    lc.setRow(0,col,M[col]);
  }
  delay(500);
  for(int col=0; col<8; col++) {
    lc.setRow(0,col,A[col]);
  }
  delay(500);
  for(int col=0; col<8; col++) {
    lc.setRow(0,col,R[col]);
  }
  delay(500);
  for(int col=0; col<8; col++) {
    lc.setRow(0,col,U[col]);
  }
  delay(500);
  for(int col=0; col<8; col++) {
    lc.setRow(0,col,K[col]);
  }
  delay(500);
  
}
```

The above code works.  When I try to refactor all of the for loops to:

```
char word[6][8] = {{A},{M},{A},{R},{U},{K}};
  
  for(int row=0; row<6; row++) {
    for(int col=0; col<8; col++) {
      lc.setRow(0,col,word[row][col]);
    }
    delay(500);
  }
```

It doesn't work.  Is there something about using a multidimensional array that I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the correct way to create the word array is like this -

`char* word[6] = {A, M, A, R, U, K};`

When you access an individual value with `word[row][col]` you treat `word[row]` as a pointer to an array, so your `word` array should be an array of array pointers

Comment: That works, thank you!  I'm used to working with JavaScript and sometime Java, so C++ takes some getting used to.